# Why Django created stacked element for custom through model

Tags: python, django

I've my own relation table and mapping two models using `through` parameter. See:

**models.py**

```
class Term(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_term"

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.TextField()

    terms = models.ManyToManyField("Term", through="Term_Post_Map")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_post"

class Term_Post_Map(models.Model):
    term = models.ForeignKey("Term", db_column="id_term")
    post = models.ForeignKey("Post", db_column="id_post")
    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_term_post_map"
```

**admin.py**

```
class AdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['title', 'content', 'terms']})
    ]
```

**Above script raise this Error:**

> 'AdminPost.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' can't include the ManyToManyField field 'terms' because 'terms' manually specifies a 'through' model.

**When I removes `'terms'` from `fieldsets` and adds to `inlines` then it works:**

```
class TermInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Term_Post_Map
    fields = ["term"]
    extra = 1

class AdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['title', 'content']})
    ]
    inlines = [TermInline]
```

**But I don't want this as in Tabular or Stacked format, like this look as:**
[image]

**why not this comes in a single ListBox element:**

When I don't maps both model using my own `through` model then it comes in single ListBox element. Same as like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django suggests using inlines when you specify a `through` model because often the intermediate table has extra fields, which couldn't be represented in a multiple select box.

In your example, you don't have any extra fields, so the easiest thing to do would be to not specify the through model. Then you can use the multiple select widget.

You might have to use the `through` model, for example you might be using a legacy database. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a quick way to enable the multiple select widget in this case.

Comment: I've more fields in Map table, not showing here. Can I pass fields name for through model?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by 'pass fields name for through model'.

Comment: If you have additional fields on the `ManyToMany` relationship table (`Term_Post_Map`) you cannot use a simple multiselect widget in the admin, because the admin would not know what values to give those additional fields when you add a new `Term` to a `Post`.